# Как создать случайный двумерный массив numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Именно средствами `numpy`. Мне нужен массив вида `a = [[b, c], [d, e] ... [x, z]]` чтобы в нем были как положительные так и отрицательные числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.uniform(low=-100, high=100, size=(4, 2))

# вывод
array([
   [-81.458     , -81.53563001],
   [ 14.38820047,  79.58667144],
   [ 10.55146126, -73.9337667 ],
   [ 12.82037855,  71.93397549]])
```

---

Либо так

```
np.random.randint(-100, 100, (3, 2))

array([
   [ 68, -63],
   [ 41,  52],
   [ 54,  85]])
```

Comment: Офигеть, всю документацию прошерстил, не видел этой функции... спасибо

Comment: А в каком разделе документации этот метод - uniform? хочу еще про него посмотреть. Это создание массива или изменение?

Comment: @Resoxape, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html?highlight=uniform#numpy.random.uniform, там есть поиск по сайту. Создание.

Answer (score 1):

В [этой](https://habr.com/ru/post/271563/) статье был момент со случайной инициализацией весов нейросети:

```
rows = 10
cols = 2
array = 2 * numpy.random.random((rows, cols)) - 1
print(array)
```

---

Возможный вывод:

```
array([[-0.90498638,  0.49846144],
       [ 0.65269211, -0.83121061],
       [ 0.03048237,  0.27927699],
       [ 0.72069673, -0.81232947],
       [ 0.27523583,  0.95059816],
       [ 0.02586882,  0.96637237],
       [ 0.88832145, -0.14137144],
       [-0.39758786,  0.43305011],
       [ 0.32713238, -0.0213639 ],
       [-0.86635081, -0.63139956]])
```

---

Также важная цитата из нее же:

> Заметьте, что она инициализируется случайным образом, и среднее
> значение равно нулю. За этим стоит достаточно сложная теория. Пока
> просто примем это как рекомендацию.